# Классы в python

Tags: python, ооп, классы

Вот такой код:

```
class Interpreter:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.code = open(filename)
        variables = {}
        with self.code as fp:
            self.lines = len(fp.readlines())
        self.current_line = 1

    def run(self):
        code = self.code
        while self.current_line <= self.lines:
            line = code.readline()
            print(f"Line {self.current_line}: {line}")
            self.current_line += 1



inter = Interpreter("programm.txt")
inter.run()
```

Должен с использованием класса вывести все строки поочередно в консоль.

Пример содержимого файла `programm.txt`:

```
line1
line2
line 3 
dmnvjsh
```

и тому подобное.

Проблема в чем. При запуске файла выдается такая ошибка:
[image]

Comment: Файл закарывается при выходе из блока `with self.code as fp:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.code` закрывается, как только оканчивается блок `with self.code as fp:`

Код лучше оформить так:

```py
class Interpreter:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.file_name = filename
        variables = {}
        with open(filename) as code:
            self.lines = len(code.readlines())
        self.current_line = 1

    def run(self):
        with open(self.file_name) as code:
            while self.current_line <= self.lines:
                line = code.readline().replace("\n", "")
                print(f"Line {self.current_line}: {line}")
                self.current_line += 1



inter = Interpreter("programm.txt")
inter.run()
```

Comment: У меня данный код выводит номер строки, но не выводит сами строки после :

Comment: Изменил, лучше хранить имя файла в классе, а открывать уже непосредственно перед использованием

Comment: Спасибо, а у меня почему то между строками расстояние. Это нормально?

Comment: Можно удалить конечный символ \n в каждой строке файла при выводе, сейчас дополню

Comment: Если вам помог код, можете пометить его как решение

Comment: Теперь работает, но в 4 строке указал символ /, а он вывел пустоту

Comment: Только при наличии в этой строке букв выводит другие символы

Comment: Дополнил, теперь в последней строке будут присутствовать все символы

Comment: Спасибо. Помогли!

Comment: Не лучше ли обойтись без `self.lines`? Без неё код будет короче и проще.